# Redirect specific sites to tomcat7 from apache

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy, tomcat7, forward

Before going on, let me say that I'm rather new to application protocols and do not fully understand how this world works ... :-)

This is the situation:

1. I have several sites being served by apache2.4.7 and those work
   well when accessing apache on port 80.
2. On the other hand, I have only one site being served by tomcat7 and it's
   also working well when accessing Tomcat on port 8080.
3. I tried to redirect traffic from apache on port 80 to that specific site on tomcat on port 8080 and cannot do it (getting a 404 error message).
4. I have also enabled the `proxy` and `proxy_http` modules, but nothing
   changed

This is the sites-enabled file for apache:

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.61.10:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        ServerName 10.10.61.10

        <Directory />
                Options None
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        Alias /racktables /var/www/racktables/wwwroot/
        <Directory /var/www/racktables/wwwroot>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.10.61.10:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass /app1/ http://10.10.61.10:8080/app1/
        ProxyPassReverse /app1/ http://10.10.61.10:8080/app1/
</VirtualHost>
```

All the information that I have read only mentioned that adding the above configuration regarding the proxy* parameters nothing more, nothing less.

However, when looking at the access.log of apache, I get the following:

```
10.10.61.62 - - [10/Nov/2015:11:32:00 -0300] "GET /app1 HTTP/1.1" 404 410 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
```

What is it that I'm missing? Any ideas or hints?

Thanks!

Lucas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some digging, the solution was to include everything under the same virtualhost such as this:

```
<VirtualHost 10.10.61.10:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        ServerName 10.10.61.10

        <Directory />
                Options None
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        Alias /racktables /var/www/racktables/wwwroot/
        <Directory /var/www/racktables/wwwroot>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPass /app1/ http://10.10.61.10:8080/app1/
        ProxyPassReverse /app1/ http://10.10.61.10:8080/app1/

</VirtualHost>
```

Regards!

Lucas